# How to use GROUPBY with the INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get the company_id with the total_of_occurance and the company_name which is in the diffrent table. I have tried the following query but somehow it's throwing some error.

```
SELECT tblhistorymaster.company_id, tblcompanymaster.company_short_name , COUNT(tblhistorymaster.company_id)
FROM tblhistorymaster
INNER JOIN tblcompanymaster ON tblcompanymaster.row_id = tblhistorymaster.company_id 
GROUP BY tblhistorymaster.company_id
```

After some search, I had found the I cant use the GROUP by with the. What will be the best way to get the result. Any suggestions will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Try repeating all unaggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`::

```
SELECT hm.company_id, cm.company_short_name, COUNT(*)
FROM tblhistorymaster hm JOIN
     tblcompanymaster cm
     ON cm.row_id = hm.company_id 
GROUP BY hm.company_id, cm.company_short_name;
```

If `cm.row_id` is the primary key or unique in `tblcompanymaster`, then you can also use:

```
SELECT cm.row_id, cm.company_short_name, COUNT(*)
FROM tblhistorymaster hm JOIN
     tblcompanymaster cm
     ON cm.row_id = hm.company_id 
GROUP BY cm.row_id;
```

This works because the `GROUP BY` key is declared to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your code like below:

```
    SELECT tblhistorymaster.company_id, tblcompanymaster.company_short_name , COUNT(tblhistorymaster.company_id) As NumberOfId
    FROM tblhistorymaster hm
    INNER JOIN tblcompanymaster cm 
ON cm.row_id = hm.company_id 
    GROUP BY NumberOfId
```